# How to make a simple windows program that starts and stops an external application

Tags: windows, powershell, language-agnostic

When launched, the program should run a shell command, like "C:\Program File\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe -startvm ..."

When launched again it should run a different command, like "C:\Program File\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe -controlvm ..."

How can I write such a program? What language can I use? I know some PHP and javascript but these don't let you create executables that run under windows :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try powershell.  Not exactly an .exe, but here is a .ps1 form (which has a 3 button GUI) that will allow you to run those commands separately.

```
function KNUCKLE-DRAGGERS-3-BUTTON-FORM {

#region Import the Assemblies
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Windows.Forms") | Out-Null
[reflection.assembly]::loadwithpartialname("System.Drawing") | Out-Null
#endregion

#region Generated Form Objects
$form1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form
$button3 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button2 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$button1 = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button
$InitialFormWindowState = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.FormWindowState
#endregion Generated Form Objects

#----------------------------------------------
#Generated Event Script Blocks
#----------------------------------------------



$handler_form1_Load= 
{


}



$handler_button1_Click= 
{

###########################################################################################################
#          Button 1 commands                                                                              #
###########################################################################################################

C:\Program File\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe -startvm 



}

$handler_button2_Click= 
{

###########################################################################################################
#          Button 2 commands                                                                              #
###########################################################################################################

C:\Program File\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe -controlvm


}

$handler_button3_Click= 
{

###########################################################################################################
#          Button 3 commands                                                                              #
###########################################################################################################


$form1.close()
#Exit

}





$OnLoadForm_StateCorrection=
{#Correct the initial state of the form to prevent the .Net maximized form issue
    $form1.WindowState = $InitialFormWindowState
}

#----------------------------------------------
#region Generated Form Code
$form1.Text = "Knuckle-Dragger Was Here"
$form1.Name = "form1"
$form1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 212
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 176
$form1.ClientSize = $System_Drawing_Size
$form1.add_Load($handler_form1_Load)

$button3.TabIndex = 2
$button3.Name = "button3"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 35
$button3.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button3.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$button3.Text = "Exit"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 36
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 114
$button3.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button3.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button3.add_Click($handler_button3_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($button3)

$button2.TabIndex = 1
$button2.Name = "button2"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 35
$button2.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button2.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$button2.Text = "Second Command"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 36
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 71
$button2.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button2.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button2.add_Click($handler_button2_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($button2)

$button1.TabIndex = 0
$button1.Name = "button1"
$System_Drawing_Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size
$System_Drawing_Size.Width = 140
$System_Drawing_Size.Height = 35
$button1.Size = $System_Drawing_Size
$button1.UseVisualStyleBackColor = $True

$button1.Text = "First Command"

$System_Drawing_Point = New-Object System.Drawing.Point
$System_Drawing_Point.X = 36
$System_Drawing_Point.Y = 28
$button1.Location = $System_Drawing_Point
$button1.DataBindings.DefaultDataSourceUpdateMode = 0
$button1.add_Click($handler_button1_Click)

$form1.Controls.Add($button1)

#endregion Generated Form Code

#Save the initial state of the form
$InitialFormWindowState = $form1.WindowState
#Init the OnLoad event to correct the initial state of the form
$form1.add_Load($OnLoadForm_StateCorrection)
#Show the Form
$form1.ShowDialog()| Out-Null

} #End Function


KNUCKLE-DRAGGERS-3-BUTTON-FORM

#
```

Comment: Thanks but I found out how to do it with batch! @echo off

if not defined TESTSRVACTIVE (
  "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" startvm "testserver" --type "headless"
  SET "TESTSRVACTIVE=1"
) else (
  "C:\Program Files\Oracle\VirtualBox\VBoxManage.exe" controlvm "testserver" poweroff
  SET "TESTSRVACTIVE="
)